# Remove finentrypunct if multicitedelim is in place

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently finalizing a citation style in biblatex for a phd thesis in history. The citation style requested sometimes is a bit... strange. This leads me to the following problem:

All citations use nearly the same citation in the footnote as in the bibliography. Those citations by default are finished with a period, i.e. `\finentrypunct` is at its default value. Now, suppose I have a cite command like

```
\cites{LitA}{LitB}
```

the current behavior is a citation like

```
Author A: Some interesting book, Somewhere 2016. Author B: Another even more interesting book, Somewhere else 2005.
```

What I would like to archive is to replace `\finentrypuct` just in those situations with a semicolon, i.e. I would like to get

```
Author A: Some interesting book, Somewhere 2016; Author B: Another even more interesting book, Somewhere else 2005.
```

I know that I just could redefine `\multicitedelim`, but this would leave me with a semicolon after the period and I see no way to remove the period beforehand.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you maybe prepare a short MWE of the general situation so we have something to play around with?

Comment: I will have a try. In this case I'm not sure how trivial the MWE will be, otherwise I would have provided it straight away.

Comment: Mhhh, I just played around with the standard styles and they are set up in a way that `\finentrypunct` is not applied in citations. Please show us a full MWE of your style, I supect there is more to it.

Comment: I have tried to answer without knowing what exactly your style looks like. I will update as soon as we get more info, but maybe this already helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem occurs if you simply typeset the `\finentrypunct` by calling `\finentrypunct` (or `\finentry` which executes `\finentrypunct`) directly. Once punctuation has been typeset, there is no easy way to remove it.

Now the naive `biblatex` solution would be to place `\finentrypunct` in a `\setunit` - as is done for most punctuation. This will not work properly, however, because we cannot guarantee that `biblatex` prints something after the `\setunit`. And if it does not, then the punctuation is lost.

The standard styles solve this problem by simply not using `\finentrypunct` in citations.

A solution for your custom style would be to do the same.

- Don't use `\finentrypunct` (or `\finentry`) in your citation commands.
- Then set `\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}`
- Finally, use a wrapper to place the full stop after the last citation. This mirrors what `\bibfootnotewrapper` and friends do.

  - Define `\newcommand*{\citepunctwrapper}[1]{#1\addperiod}`
  - Use it for `\cite` as wrapper

    ```
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\citepunctwrapper]
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
      {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
       \usebibmacro{cite}}
      {\multicitedelim}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
    ```

    and also for `\cites`

    ```
      \DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\citepunctwrapper]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}
    ```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\newcommand*{\citepunctwrapper}[1]{#1\addperiod}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\citepunctwrapper]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\citepunctwrapper]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

\begin{document}
\cites{sigfridsson}{worman}
\end{document}
```